# Multiple Classes that implements IHttpHandler (Image uploaders)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Apologies if this seems quite vague, trying to understand it myself. What I'm trying to do is upload images using a class that implements IHttpHandler.

All works fine with one class but if I add another class that implements the same interface to upload an image, it reverts back to the other. This is very difficult to explain, so I'll add some code:

Code below allows me to upload an image and works perfect:

```
public class UploadifyHandler : IHttpHandler
{

            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {      
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
                Single maxWidthPx = 75;
                string filename = postedFile.FileName;
                var Extension = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower();
                string savepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/profile/");
             }
    }
```

The above code works perfect but now if i added another class that implements the same interface it still works but its uses none of its logic and reverts to the above code block:

```
public class LogoHandler : IHttpHandler
{

   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
                Single maxWidthPx = 150;
                string filename = postedFile.FileName;
                var Extension = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower();

                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("/images/campaign/" + user.campaignName + "/");

                string savepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/campaign/" + user.campaignName + "/");
    }
}
```

The logic in the latter is going to be considerably different, so ideally I'd like to have a separate class.

Just to re-iterate If i use the second code block to upload an image, it uses the first code block to process the upload.

I may be missing something very simple thus needing a fresh pair of eyes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Since routing code is missing from post (not even clear if it is ASP.Net. ASP.Net MVC or some custom service) you better start with [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and than possibly update the question with details you explain to the rubber duck.

Comment: Haha cheers for the rubber duck link...This may help me in the long run (thumbs up) I thought it was quite obvious that it was .Net. Anyhow, it's webforms.

Comment: Post your routing code. Or are you using ashx files?

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply...I'm using ashx files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments this sounds like a routing issue.

Generic handlers, implemented with the IHttpHandler interface, can either use a .ashx file to define their endpoint or it can defined in the web.config file. For ashx files, the filename becomes the address and the IHttpHandler implementation is specified by a WebHandler Class declaration. For example:

[image: ashx route example]

, would provide and endpoint for your LogHandler class at ~/LogoHanlderEndpoint.ashx.

To setup the same thing in the web.config file you add an element to the handlers section in system webserver configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="LogoHandler" path="LogoHandlerEndpoint.ashx" verb="*" type="LogoHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Here the type attribute defines the class that implements IHttpHandler. With this method the path can be anything, the .ashx extension is not required.

Comment: Great answer...The routing was the problem and for some reason it was referencing the wrong file. Your answer is outstanding and may help future users, so going to mark this as answered. Great work.